# How to Apply FiltersFeature to Grid in ExtJS MVC

Tags: javascript, extjs

I found this post [How to add filters in grid column headers in extjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085186/how-to-add-filters-in-grid-column-headers-in-extjs#comment24719938_17089765) however, I don't know how to apply it in my code, which uses MVC pattern.  For example, this is my grid:

```
Ext.define('RateManagement.view.Grids.AirShipmentGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'AirShipmentGrid',
    plugins: [
        {
            clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
            autoCancel: false,
            ptype: 'rowediting',
            pluginId: 'rowediting'
        },
        'bufferedrenderer'
    ],
    loadMask: true,
    columns: [
        {text: 'Home Country', dataIndex: 'homeCountry', width: 175, sortable: true},
        {text: 'Home Location', dataIndex: 'homeLocation', width: 175},
        {text: 'Host Country', dataIndex: 'hostCountry', width: 175},
        {text: 'Host Location', dataIndex: 'hostLocation', width: 175},
        {text: 'Assignee Air Shipment & Insurance', dataIndex: 'assigneeAirShipmentPlusInsurance', width: 200, xtype: 'numbercolumn',
            editor: { xtype: 'numberfield', allowBlank: false, minValue: 0, blankText: 'Rate is required.', invalidText: 'Rate must be positive.' }},
        {text: 'Dependent Air Shipment & Insurance', dataIndex: 'dependentAirShipmentPlusInsurance', width: 200, xtype: 'numbercolumn',
            editor: { xtype: 'numberfield', allowBlank: false, minValue: 0, blankText: 'Rate is required.', invalidText: 'Rate must be positive.' }},
        {text: 'Small Container & Insurance', dataIndex: 'smallContainerPlusInsurance', width: 175, xtype: 'numbercolumn',
            editor: { xtype: 'numberfield', allowBlank: false, minValue: 0, blankText: 'Rate is required.', invalidText: 'Rate must be positive.' }},
        {text: 'Large Container & Insurance', dataIndex: 'largeContainerPlusInsurance', width: 175, xtype: 'numbercolumn',
            editor: { xtype: 'numberfield', allowBlank: false, minValue: 0, blankText: 'Rate is required.', invalidText: 'Rate must be positive.' }},
        {text: 'Rate Currency', dataIndex: 'currencyId', xtype: 'currency-column' }
    ]
});
```

Where do I put this part?

```
filters = {
        ftype: 'filters',
        encode: false,
        local: true
    };
```

I tried adding an `initComponent: function() {` but it gave me an error.

Note:  I am using ExtJS version 4.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the filter feature within your `grid` definition:

```
Ext.define('RateManagement.view.Grids.AirShipmentGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'AirShipmentGrid',
    requires:['Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature'],
    plugins: [
        {
            clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
            autoCancel: false,
            ptype: 'rowediting',
            pluginId: 'rowediting'
        },
        'bufferedrenderer'
    ],
    features: [{
        ftype: 'filters',
        encode: false,
        local: true,
        filters: [{
            type: 'filterType',
            dataIndex:'fieldToFilter'
        }]
    }],
    loadMask: true,
    columns: [
        {text: 'Home Country', dataIndex: 'homeCountry', width: 175, sortable: true},
        {text: 'Home Location', dataIndex: 'homeLocation', width: 175},
        {text: 'Host Country', dataIndex: 'hostCountry', width: 175},
        {text: 'Host Location', dataIndex: 'hostLocation', width: 175},
        {text: 'Assignee Air Shipment & Insurance', dataIndex: 'assigneeAirShipmentPlusInsurance', width: 200, xtype: 'numbercolumn',
            editor: { xtype: 'numberfield', allowBlank: false, minValue: 0, blankText: 'Rate is required.', invalidText: 'Rate must be positive.' }},
        {text: 'Dependent Air Shipment & Insurance', dataIndex: 'dependentAirShipmentPlusInsurance', width: 200, xtype: 'numbercolumn',
            editor: { xtype: 'numberfield', allowBlank: false, minValue: 0, blankText: 'Rate is required.', invalidText: 'Rate must be positive.' }},
        {text: 'Small Container & Insurance', dataIndex: 'smallContainerPlusInsurance', width: 175, xtype: 'numbercolumn',
            editor: { xtype: 'numberfield', allowBlank: false, minValue: 0, blankText: 'Rate is required.', invalidText: 'Rate must be positive.' }},
        {text: 'Large Container & Insurance', dataIndex: 'largeContainerPlusInsurance', width: 175, xtype: 'numbercolumn',
            editor: { xtype: 'numberfield', allowBlank: false, minValue: 0, blankText: 'Rate is required.', invalidText: 'Rate must be positive.' }},
        {text: 'Rate Currency', dataIndex: 'currencyId', xtype: 'currency-column' }
    ]
});
```

There is a decent non mvc example in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html)

Comment: Thanks so much.  Do you know where the filters -> type options are listed?  I have some decimal types I would like to filter by, not just strings.

Comment: @user1477388 They are listed in the **left hand tree** in [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.filter.BooleanFilter)